# Can I use one S3 bucket for upload different java lambda function?

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently I am using different `S3 bucket` for every function.

Ex. I have 3 **Java Lambda Function** created on `Eclipse IDE`.

1. RegisterUser
2. LoginUser
3. ResetPassword

I am uploading lambda function through `Eclipse IDE`,

I have to upload function through **Amazon S3 Bucket**.

I create 3 `Amazon S3 Bucket` for upload all 3 function.

**My Question is :** Can I upload all 3 Lambda Function using one `Amazon S3 Bucket`?

or

I have to create separate `Amazon S3 Bucket`for all function.?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upload to a bucket. You can upload the function code via the command line as well. They only recommend not using the web interface for large Lambda functions, all other methods are ok, and command line is a very good option.

However, if you really want to upload to a bucket first, just give each zip file that contains the function code a different filename and you're good.

Comment: Can I archive this by using only one bucket for every function?